# Sort on field completeness of Solr Documents

Tags: solr

I have this Solr field

```xml
<field name="listing_thumbnail" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
```

Now when the results are shown the fields without the field value should be shown at the last. Is this possible in SOLR? To generalise is it possible to sort documents on field completeness?

Comment: So you want the documents that have no value in that `listing_thumbnail` to be sorted to the back of the result?

Comment: @cheffe That's right.More along the lines of sortMissingLast="true".

Comment: Ok, so you know already about `sortMissingLast="true"`? I wanted to point you there. That is not an option?

Comment: But I wanted a solution more which does not use sorting but something like a query which just pushes these documents without altering the results which do have these fields?

Comment: Are you using dismax/edismax or the standard request handler?

Comment: I am using a standard request handler.

Comment: Hm, what I could offer requires to change the query handler to dismax/edismax and the field to be `indexed=true`. So a change to your solrconfig.xml and a re-index. Does the latter pose a problem?

Comment: No I will use an edismax,shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [bq (Boost Query) Parameter of the dismax/edismax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Thebq%28BoostQuery%29Parameter) query handler. This allows to query if a field is empty or not and then affect the score, but to do so the field needs to be `indexed=true`.

If you had your field indexed you could add `bq=(listing_thumbnail:*)` - this would give a push to all documents with a value in that field.